# Log analysis in Pig

Tags: regex, apache-pig, hadoop2, log-analysis

I have a .txt file which looks like :

```
2017-06-22 23:19:05,758 use database stocks
2017-06-22 23:21:27,056 CREATE TABLE stocksdata ( stock_exchange string,

stock_symbol string, date TIMESTAMP,
```

The regex I wrote is `^(\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2})\\s+(\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}),(\\d{3})\\s((?i)(create|select|use).*)$`.

But my output is

```
2017-06-22 23:19:05,758 use database stocks
2017-06-22 23:21:27,056 CREATE TABLE stocksdata ( stock_exchange string,
```

It is not taking lines in next line of input viz **stock_symbol string, date TIMESTAMP,**. I need to capture this line as well.

Comment: Do you mean you have a two line string? Try adding `(?si)` at the start of the pattern (then, you may remove the `(?i)` from your pattern).

Comment: Yes Wiktor I have 2 line string and this is what I did "^?si(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})\s+(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}),(\d{3})\s((create|select|use).*)$"

which didn't work out.I get nothing in the output when I run pig script.
Thanks

Comment: No, I wrote "*add `(?si)`*" - you can try `(?si)^(\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2})\\s+(\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}),(\\d{3})\\s((create|select|use).*)$`

Comment: Wiktor - I tried it and I get same output as I was getting earlier. Are you trying with Pig ??

Comment: No, I just know it uses Java regex flavor. See [here](https://regex101.com/r/yjFxFR/1) what it matches. If it is not what you need, specify what you need to get in the end.

Comment: Can u post your pig script?

Comment: ok so what you are suggesting is cool but try adding a random line in your input , your regex will match because of ?so I think.

Please check this link  http://regexr.com/3g879 . you will see that third line is not getting captured which is wha I wanna capture.

Comment: Hi TKHN,

 Right now  I only want to parse through and save it as .csv so here is the script ::

data = LOAD '/home/cloudera/dataset/test.log' USING org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.MyRegExLoader('^(\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2})\\s+(\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}),(\\d{3})\\s(.*)((?i)(create|select|use).*)$') AS (dt: chararray, time1: chararray, port: chararray, random1: chararray, query: chararray);

STORE data INTO '/home/cloudera/ash1111' USING PigStorage(',');

Comment: Sorry for posting like this. I don't know best way to post it in a good format

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following pattern:

```
^(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})\s+(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}),(\d{3})\s((?i)(create|select|use)[\s\S]*)$
```

I replaced the `.*` at the end with `[\s\S]*`, because the latter consumes new lines.

Comment: No need to use `[\s\S]` if a dot with a DOTALL modifier can do the same - and quicker.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, this expression has worked out

**(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})\s+(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}),(\d{3})\s(\w{4})\s(.*)(()(create\s|select\s|use\s).*(.*\s\S?\D.*\s\D)*)**

Thank you for replies